# How to catch all the possible scenarios in java

Tags: android, exception, memory

I'm developing a videogame in Android which closes unexpectedly and randomly. The case is I have the following code envolving my game loop:

```
    try {
        //game loop
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        //...
    }
```

For some reason, the app is not entering any of those catchs. I thought it was a memory problem, but with the 'OutOfMemoryError' it should be covered right? Or this just covers when we demand a lot of memory all the sudden?

I was wondering if there is any catch condition to capture ALL the possible situations because this is driving me crazy...

Comment: `catch(Exception e)` will grab any exception that occurs. The OutOfMemoryError catch will never occur. Just FYI

Comment: Well the Exception e should handle all of the exceptions since it is the base class. Can't comment much based on some generic code you posted.

Comment: What is your Logcat-output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at any code. I would posit that perhaps you have an endless loop in your gameloop and it is causing the app to be unresponsive. Which is causing the OS to handle any exceptions or issues raised.

Comment: hmmm I have some recursive operations in the game, but they are not inifinite. This problems I'm having just happen with old devices... so it has to be something related to performance. Is it possible an application decides to close because it thinks the actual operation is running is taking so long? It could be... but in a better device, it never closes.

Comment: Are you getting an "App is not responding" popup?

Comment: No. It just closes, without saying anything. That's why I'm so mad at it. I can't figure out what is going on. I was also wondering if it might be because the mobile becomes so hot while I'm playing...

Comment: If that were the case the whole phone would probably shut down, not just the app. What are the recursive operations you're doing?